# Why the native heap already has 5 mb in Application's onCreate()

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory

I put this in the first line of on Create() in the Application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("test", "application oncreate");
    showMemoryStats();
    super.onCreate();
}
```

Where showMemoryStats() is:

```
public static void showMemoryStats() {

    double nativeUsage = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize(); 
    Log.i("test", "nativeUsage: " + nativeUsage);
    //current heap size 
    double heapSize =  Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    Log.i("test", "heapSize: " + heapSize);
    //amount available in heap 
    double heapRemaining = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();   
    Log.i("test", "heapRemaining: " + heapRemaining);
    double memoryAvailable = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() - (heapSize - heapRemaining) - nativeUsage;
    Log.i("test", "memoryAvailable: " + memoryAvailable);

}
```

I start the app after full deinstallation. I get:

> 07-03 17:39:05.212: I/test(19016): nativeUsage: 5649968.0
>
> 07-03 17:39:05.212: I/test(19016): heapSize: 4710384.0
>
> 07-03 17:39:05.212: I/test(19016): heapRemaining: 1705056.0
>
> 07-03 17:39:05.212: I/test(19016): memoryAvailable: 2.4899136E7

This is already 5 mb in native heap, why? Is that normal?

Comment: Depends. It should be normal.

Comment: You are welcome to dump your heap and examine it in MAT to find out.

Comment: The native heap isn't shown in MAT. At least I was not able to see it. Only normal heap.